# AngularJS orderBy same property as ngModel throws $digest error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

When I try to orderBy a property that I am binding to in a `ng-repeat` I get a `$digest` error.
I think it is occurring because in one digest the `ng-model` value is updating, which effects the parents `orderBy` clause. I do not know how to get around this.

### Plunker (Update)

This shows the issue occurring. Be sure to open the console!

http://embed.plnkr.co/rGLagq/preview

### JS

```
var options = [
    {
        name: 'test',
        isSelected: true
    }, 
    {
        name: 'another test',
        isSelected: false
    }
];
```

### HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="option in options | orderBy:'-isSelected'">
        <label>
             <input type="checkbox"
                    ng-model="option.isSelected"> {{option.name}}
        </label>
    </div>
```

### Error

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused by a bug in angular:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10014

Should hopefully be fixed by: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/9808

Target fix version: `1.3.4`

Comment: I can confirm this was fixed in `1.3.4`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have manual calls like $scope.$apply() or $scope.$digest in your code that will kick off digest cycles manually. The code you are showing here should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

The inprog error occurs sometimes when the you trigger code (such as a DOM event) programmatically (from within Angular), which is normally called by an external trigger. This kind of error is normally complex to handle. Your best bet is to use $timeout to wait for digest to complete and then do your tasks. I've modified your code to provide the intended functionality using $timeout. Please take a look at below code. To know more about issues regarding inprog, see this link

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="option in options | orderBy:'-isSelected'">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-click="option.selected()"> {{option.name}}
    </label>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    var myScope = $scope;
    myScope.options = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        myScope.options.push(new function(){
            var myself = this;
            myself.name = 'Tag ' + i;
            myself.isSelected = false;
            myself.selected = function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                    myself.isSelected = !myself.isSelected;
                    myScope.$apply();
                }, 0, false);
            };
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice thinking outside of the box. 

However, the checkbox is now no longer bound to the isSelected variable. When `isSelected` changes it will not update the checkbox. Initial state setting (setting `isSelected` to `true`) would also not work

Comment: isSelected is not directly bound. But by using function selected(), we are changing the isSelected and then calling the apply ourselves to update the UI. This thing works without issues.